# AND query and Updating database query in Django?

Tags: database, django

I want to retrieve a data where id=1 and flag='D' in Django. I would use WHERE with AND in SQL. How can I do it in Django? I tried:

```
File.objects.filter(user_id=1 AND flag='D')
```

But it doesn't work.

And another thing, I can I update only one filed of the the database in Django i.e `updating flag='D' to flag='F'` with everything same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
File.objects.filter(user_id=1, flag='D')
```

This should get you all File that has user_id=1 and flag='D'

For Updating a column you should use update on queryset

```
File.objects.filter(user_id=5).update(flag="D")
```

You can also do

```
q = File.objects.filter(user_id=1, flag='D')
```

print `q.query` to see the sql generated by Django ORM

Answer (score 0):

If you want to filter multiple record then use "filter", because it returns a queryset

```
File.objects.filter(user_id=1, flag='D')
```

In case you are interested in a single unique record so please use "get", as it returns a single object

```
File.objects.get(user_id=1, flat='D')
```